# Prove that if square root of ${m\over n}$ is rational, then $m$ and $n$ are both perfect squares

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers with no common factor. I have to prove that if square root of ${m\over n}$ is rational, then $m$ and $n$ are both perfect squares, that is to say there exist integers $p$ and $q$ such that $m = p^2$ and $n = q^2$.

Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Is it possible to express a rational number as a fraction "in lowest terms" two different ways?  Why or why not?  If not then if $\sqrt {\frac mn} = \frac rs$ then $\frac mn = (\frac rs)^2 = \frac {r^2}{s^2}$.  Which one of those two are "in lowest terms"?

Answer (score 0):

If the square root of $\frac mn$ is rational then there exist two integers, $r,s$ so that $r$ and $s$ have no factors in common so that $(\frac rs)^2=\frac {r^2}{s^2} = \frac mn$.

Now, we are assuming that $\frac mn$ are in "lowest terms"; that is $m,n$ have no factors in common.  And we are assuming that $r, s$ have no factors in common.

So my questions to you are:

1. If $r$ and $s$ have no factors in common, is it possible for $r^2$
   and $s^2$ to have factor in common?  And if they have no factors in
   common is $\frac {r^2}{s^2}$ in "lowest terms"?
2. Is it possible for a rational number to be expressed "in lowest
   terms" in two different ways?
3. If $\frac {r^2}{s^2} = \frac {m}{n}$ is it possible that $m \ne
   r^2$?  Is it possible that $n \ne s^2$?

It seems we always take 2) for granted.  Maybe we need to concentrate on how to prove 2).

======

There are basic things we take for granted.

1)  That a rational number can be written as a fraction between two integers.

That's actually a definition.

2) That every rational number has a *unique* way of being written "in lowest terms" as $w = \frac mn$ where $m,n$ are integers, than $n$ is positive (and $m$ will be positive, negative, or zero if $w$ is), and that $m$ and $n$ have no integer factors in common other than $1$ (or in other words $\gcd(m,n) = 1$).

How do we know that every rational number has a *unique* expression in lowest terms?  Um.... Let me get back to you.

3) Unique prime factorization:  Every positive integer $k$ has a unique expression as a product of powers of primes.

Why?  Um... let me get back to you.

So this makes these question easy.  If $w = \frac mn$ is the *unique* expression in lowest terms of rational $w$.  And if $\sqrt{w}$ is rational.  Then $\sqrt = \frac rs$ where $\frac rs$ is the unique expression *in lowest terms* of $\sqrt{w}$.

So $\sqrt{w} = \frac rs$

$w = (\frac rs)^2 = \frac {r^2}{s^2}$.

Now $r$ and $s$ have no factors in common.  So $r^2$ and $s^2$ have no factors in common.  So $w=\frac {r^2}{s^2}$ is in lowest terms.

But $w = \frac mn$ is *also* in lowest terms.  And the lowest terms expression is *unique*.  So if $w = \frac mn = \frac {r^2}{s^2}$ are both in lowest terms, then $m = r^2, n = s^2$.

Period.

That's it.

...or... you can put it in terms of prime factors.

If $\frac mn = \frac {r^2}{s^2}$ then $ms^2 = nr^2$.  If $p$ is a prime factor of $m$ then $p|nr^2$.  So $p|n$ or $p|r^2$.  But $p \not \mid n$ because $m,n$ are relatively prime.  So $p|r^2$ so $p|r$ so $p^2|r^2$.  So $p^2|nr^2$ and $p^2|ms^2$.  So $p|\frac mp s^2$ so $p|\frac mp$ or $p| s^2$.  But $p\not \mid s^2$ because $p|r$ and $r,s$ are relatively prime.  So $p|\frac mp$ so $p^2|m$.

Repeat this for every prime factor of $m$ and you will see that every prime factor divides $m$ and even number of times.  So $m$ is a perfect square and $m = r^2$.  Likewise $n = s^2$.

But you don't *have* to do this.  As "lowest terms" are *unique* and $\frac mn = \frac {r^2}{s^2}$ are *both* in lowest terms... $m$ and $n$ *are* $r^2$ and $s^2$.

Comment: Yes. you are right. I am getting problem in proving m=r^2 and n=s^2. Can u help me in proving this??

Comment: Well, If you know $\frac mn$ is in lowest terms and $\frac {r^2} {s^2}$ is in lowest terms and $\frac mn = \frac {r^2}{s^2}$ and you know a rational number has one unique way of being expressed as a fraction in lowest terms, then you are done.  But if you want to do this more directly consider the prime factors.